# How to use hex() without 0x in Python?

Tags: python

The `hex()` function in python, puts the leading characters `0x` in front of the number. Is there anyway to tell it NOT to put them? So `0xfa230` will be `fa230`.

The code is

```
import fileinput
f = open('hexa', 'w')
for line in fileinput.input(['pattern0.txt']):
   f.write(hex(int(line)))
   f.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 276, accepted):

### (Recommended)

#### [Python 3 f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings): Answered by [@GringoSuave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52674814/1219006)

```
>>> i = 3735928559
>>> f'{i:x}'
'deadbeef'
```

---

### Alternatives:

#### [`format` builtin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) (good for single values only)

```
>>> format(3735928559, 'x')
'deadbeef'
```

#### And sometimes we still may need to use [`str.format` formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) in certain situations [@Eumiro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16414606/1219006)

(Though I would still recommend `f-strings` in most situations)

```
>>> '{:x}'.format(3735928559)
'deadbeef'
```

#### (Legacy) `f-strings` should solve all of your needs, but [`printf`-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) is what we used to do [@msvalkon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16414614/1219006)

```
>>> '%x' % 3735928559
'deadbeef'
```

#### Without string formatting [@jsbueno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73154538/1219006)

```
>>> i = 3735928559
>>> i.to_bytes(4, "big").hex()
'deadbeef'
```

### Hacky Answers (avoid)

#### `hex(i)[2:]` [@GuillaumeLemaître](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2312677/guillaume-lema%C3%AEtre)

```
>>> i = 3735928559
>>> hex(i)[2:]
'deadbeef'
```

This relies on string slicing instead of using a function / method made specifically for formatting as `hex`. This is why it may give unexpected output for negative numbers:

```
>>> i = -3735928559
>>> hex(i)[2:]
'xdeadbeef'
>>> f'{i:x}'
'-deadbeef'
```

Comment: This may have been the best answer at the time, but today f-strings are a much nicer solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52674814/4298200

Comment: @Neuron-FreedomforUkraine Thanks I updated the answer to be a more comprehensive guide now

Comment: great, happy to see you included it! I took the freedom to edit away the "update" notice. read the meta site I linked in the edit summary if you are curious

Comment: Also, maybe it is worth mentioning `int.to_bytes` and `bytes.hex`  - as a way that do not rely on string formatting.  (I've just added a new answer using these)

Comment: @jsbueno I think your answer is pretty cool and gave you an upvote but do you think I should be recommending this as an alternative to eg. `f'{i:x}'` It just seems like eg. `f'{i:x}'` is easier than `i.to_bytes(4, "big").hex()`

Comment: no - for most use cases, the f-string formatting is more straightforward, and I even mention that on my answer. It could be mentioned above as  a method not involving going through string representation/manipulation - just that.

Comment: You could use something like this to ensure that the numbers are represented by a specific amount of hex digits. In this example all numbers will be represented by two hex digits. So 10 will be equal to 0A and not just A: `f"{self.red * 255:02x}{self.green * 255:02x}{self.blue * 255:02x}"`

Answer (score 67):

Use this code:

```
'{:x}'.format(int(line))
```

it allows you to specify a number of digits too:

```
'{:06x}'.format(123)
# '00007b'
```

For Python 2.6 use

```
'{0:x}'.format(int(line))
```

or

```
'{0:06x}'.format(int(line))
```

Comment: Using the `format()` function is easier, you are not using any templating functionality, only formatting. If all your template contains is `{:..}` for *one* value, move to `format(value, '..')` instead.

Comment: To be able to specify the number of digits is very helpful.

Answer (score 26):

You can simply write

```
hex(x)[2:]
```

to get the first two characters removed.

Comment: This is not safe against future changes of the output.

Comment: Also in Python 2 with long numbers it produces weird ouput: `>>> hex(3735928559)[2:]`
`'deadbeefL'`

Comment: @esseks: I doubt they'll change the output format before the next major release. You'll have other incompatibilities anyway.

Comment: This will break if `x` is negative.

Comment: No, it can't break because `x` is never negative.

Answer (score 23):

**Python 3.6+:**

```
>>> i = 240
>>> f'{i:x}'  # 02x to pad with zeros
'f0'
```

Answer (score 8):

Old style string formatting:

```
In [3]: "%x" % 127
Out[3]: '7f'
```

New style

```
In [7]: '{:x}'.format(127)
Out[7]: '7f'
```

Using capital letters as format characters yields uppercase hexadecimal

```
In [8]: '{:X}'.format(127)
Out[8]: '7F'
```

[Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) are here.

Answer (score 6):

`'x'` - Outputs the number in base 16, using **lower-case** letters for the digits above 9.

```
>>> format(3735928559, 'x')
'deadbeef'
```

`'X'` - Outputs the number in base 16, using **upper-case** letters for the digits above 9.

```
>>> format(3735928559, 'X')
'DEADBEEF'
```

You can find more information about that in Python's documentation:

- [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec)
- [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#format)

Answer (score 6):

### F-strings

Python 3's [formatted literal strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) (f-strings) support the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec), which designates `x` for hexadecimal numbers. The output doesn't include `0x`.

So you can do this:

```
>>> f"{3735928559:x}"
'deadbeef'
```

See the spec for other bases like binary, octal, etc.

### Edit: `str.removeprefix`

Since Python 3.9, there is now a [`str.removeprefix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix) method, which allows you to write the following more obvious code:

```
>>> hexadecimal = hex(3735928559)
>>> hexadecimal.removeprefix('0x')
'deadbeef'
```

Not that this does NOT work for negative numbers ❌:

```
>>> negadecimal = hex(-3735928559)
>>> negadecimal.removeprefix('0x')
'-0xdeadbeef'
```

Comment: [Gringo Suave's answer](/a/52674814/4518341) also covers this

Answer (score 1):

Besides going through string formatting, it is interesting to have in mind that when working with numbers and their hexadecimal representation we usually are dealing with byte-content, and interested in how bytes relate.

The `bytes` class in Python 3 had been enriched with methods over the 3.x series, and `int.to_bytes` combined with the `bytes.hex()` provide full control of the hex-digits output, while preserving the semantics of the transform (not to mention, holding the intermediate "bytes" object ready to be used in any binary protocol that requires the number):

```
In [8]: i = 3735928559

In [9]: i.to_bytes(4, "big").hex()
Out[9]: 'deadbeef'
```

Besides that, `bytes.hex()` allow some control over the output, such as specifying a separator for the hex digits:

```
In [10]: bytes.hex?
Docstring:
Create a string of hexadecimal numbers from a bytes object.

  sep
    An optional single character or byte to separate hex bytes.
  bytes_per_sep
    How many bytes between separators.  Positive values count from the
    right, negative values count from the left.

Example:
>>> value = b'\xb9\x01\xef'
>>> value.hex()
'b901ef'
>>> value.hex(':')
'b9:01:ef'
>>> value.hex(':', 2)
'b9:01ef'
>>> value.hex(':', -2)
'b901:ef'
```

(That said, in most scenarios just a quick print is wanted, I'd probably just  go through f-string formatting, as in the accepted answer:  `f"{mynumber:04x}"` - for the simple reason of "less things to remember")

Answer (score -1):

While all of the previous answers will work, a lot of them have caveats like not being able to handle both positive and negative numbers or only work in Python 2 or 3. The version below works in both Python 2 and 3 and for positive and negative numbers:

Since Python returns a string hexadecimal value from hex() we can use string.replace to remove the 0x characters regardless of their position in the string (which is important since this differs for positive and negative numbers).

```
hexValue = hexValue.replace('0x','')
```

**EDIT:** wjandrea made a good point in that the above implementation doesn't handle values that contain 0X instead of 0x, which can occur in int literals. With this use case in mind, you can use the following case-insensitive implementation for Python 2 and 3:

```
import re
hexValue = re.sub('0x', '', hexValue, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: This works, but why remove `'0x'` when you could avoid adding it in the first place with the format spec `x`? [jamylak's answer](/a/16414603/4518341) and [Gringo Suave's answer](/a/52674814/4518341) cover it.

Comment: @wjandrea I'm not sure why I thought jamylak's answer didn't work on both Python 2 and 3. I just tested it on Python 2.7.2 and 3.7.8 and it worked on both of these. Also, thank you for pointing out the edge case that my original answer wasn't addressing. I've provided an updated implementation that addresses this use case as well.

Answer (score -3):

Decimal to Hexadecimal,
it worked

```
hex(number).lstrip("0x").rstrip("L")
```

Comment: This doesn't work for non-positive numbers. `number = 0` -> `''`. `number = -1` -> `'-0x1'`