# Returning in for loops python

Tags: python, function, for-loop, return, program-entry-point

I've been trying a while now but i just can't seem to get it right.
I'm a starting programmer and have to do an assignment for school. The program should ask the user for a number and print a diamond shape, based on this number.
Now I've got it working fine.. but I have print statements outside my main. How do i get this inside my main?

my code:

```
def loop(start, eind, step, ei):
    for a in range (start, eind, step):       
        for b in range(a):                  
            print(" ", end="")                
        for c in range(ei+1, a, -1):
            print(a, end="")            
        for d in range(a, ei):           
            print(a, end="")             
    print("")  

def main():
    print("Welcome!  :) ")
    loop(y,0,-1,y)
    loop(2,y+1,1,y)
```

Hope you guys can help me out!
By the way, I've got more code for this program but that's not relevant (like asking the user for "y").

Comment: *but I have print statements outside my main. How do i get this inside my main?* what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the indentation you have pasted is correct (and `y` variable is defined in global scope), your current code does not produce a diamond shape , it would only get produced correctly if the last `print("")` inside the `loop()` function was indented inside the `for` loop.

Given that, what you may want to look into is [generator functions](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) with [`yield` statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) . Example -

```
def loop(start, eind, step, ei):
    for a in range (start, eind, step):       
        for b in range(a):                  
            yield " "                
        for c in range(ei+1, a, -1):
            yield a            
        for d in range(a, ei):           
            yield a
        yield '\n'

def main():
    print("Welcome!  :) ")
    for x in loop(y,0,-1,y):
        print(x,end="")
    for x in loop(2,y+1,1,y):
        print(x,end="")
```

This assumes `y` variable is defined in global scope.

Demo -

```
>>> def loop(start, eind, step, ei):
...     for a in range (start, eind, step):
...         for b in range(a):
...             yield " "
...         for c in range(ei+1, a, -1):
...             yield a
...         for d in range(a, ei):
...             yield a
...         yield '\n'
...
>>> def main():
...     print("Welcome!  :) ")
...     y = 5
...     for x in loop(y,0,-1,y):
...         print(x,end="")
...     for x in loop(2,y+1,1,y):
...         print(x,end="")
...
...
>>> main()
Welcome!  :)
     5
    444
   33333
  2222222
 111111111
  2222222
   33333
    444
     5
```

Comment: You might look into the string format() method to make the print statements easier to follow and extend. [Here's an example for a similar question about printing pyramids.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32427982/2125392) Though that may be beside the point, since the problem seems designed to learn about looping.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to practice some more with this.