# converting hex to int, the 'L' character

Tags: python

I have a 64bit hex number and I want to convert it to unsigned integer. I run

```
>>> a = "ffffffff723b8640"
>>> int(a,16)
18446744071331087936L
```

So what is the 'L' at the end of the number?

Using the following commands also don't help

```
>>> int(a,16)[:-1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'long' object is unsubscriptable
>>> int(a,16).rstrip("L")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

Comment: It means Long integer.

You can [strip the L][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218164/python-integer-to-hexadecimal-extra-characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to apply string methods to an integer. But the string representation of a long integer doesn't have the `L` at the end:

```
In [1]: a = "ffffffff723b8640"

In [2]: int(a, 16)
Out[2]: 18446744071331087936L

In [3]: str(int(a, 16))
Out[3]: '18446744071331087936'
```

The `__repr__` does, though (as @mgilson notes):

```
In [4]: repr(int(a, 16))
Out[4]: '18446744071331087936L'

In [5]: repr(int(a, 16))[:-1]
Out[5]: '18446744071331087936'
```

Answer (score 4):

Python2.x has 2 classes of integer (neither of them are unsigned btw).  There is the usual class `int` which is based on your system's concept of an integer (often a 4-byte integer).  There's also the arbitrary "precision" type of integer `long`.  They behave the same in *almost*<sup>1</sup> all circumstances and `int` objects automatically convert to `long` if they overflow.  Don't worry about the `L` in the representation -- It just means your integer is too big for `int` (there was an Overflow) so python automatically created a `long` instead.

It is also worth pointing out that in python3.x, they removed python2.x's `int` in favor of always using `long`.  Since they're now always using `long`, they renamed it to `int` as that name is much more common in code.  [PEP-237](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/) gives more rational behind this decision.

<sup><sup>1</sup>The only time they behave differently that I can think of is that long's `__repr__` adds that extra `L` on the end that you're seeing.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

you can't call `rstrip` on an integer, you have to call it on the *string representation* of the integer.

```
>>> a = "ffffffff723b8640"
>>> b = int(a,16)
>>> c = repr(b).rstrip("L")
>>> c
'18446744071331087936'
```

Note however, that this would only be for displaying the number or something. Turning the string back into an integer will append the 'L' again:

```
>>> int(c)
18446744071331087936L
```